# Using default values for arguments in a wrapper class

Tags: c++, wrapper, default-value

I came across this syntax:

```
class Wrapper
{
static const char * libname;

public:
  Wrapper(void);

 static int (__stdcall *myfunction)(int val1, int val1, char val3);
}
```

`myfunction` is from a C library and has this signature in the headerfile:

```
int __stdcall myfunction(int val1, int val1, char val3);
```

Now when this function is called from the wrapper class...

```
Wrapper::myfunction(1,2, 3);
```

...I want to be able to define standard values for the arguments so I can also call it with less arguments or none. But I am not sure where to define them. Inside the wrapper class and I get this error:

```
error C2383: 'Wrapper::myfunction' : default-arguments are not allowed on this symbol
```

I could really use some help here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Define the static function member inside the class the following way

```
static int __stdcall myfunction(int val1 = 1, int val2 = 2, char val3 = 3)
{
    return ::myfunction( val1, val2, val3 );
}
```

Comment: Inside what class? The Wrapper?